# Why is my XPath based on text content failing?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I'm trying to match this `a` link:

```
<a href="/collection/accessories_wall?productType=Cases+%26+Sleeves&amp;productType=Screen+Protectors&amp;compatibilityCategory=Phone" class="product-link" data-product-id="cases_protection" xpath="1">
  Cases &amp; protection
  
</a>
```

Tried:

```
//a[contains(text(),'Cases &amp; protection')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to escape the ampersand `&` with `&amp;`.
So try this instead:

```
//a[contains(normalize-space(text()),'Cases &amp; protection')]
```

**EDIT:**
I added the `normalize-space(...)` function to only check the core text and not the surrounding spaces. Maybe that does help you.

Comment: Good point (+1) but it looks like OP had `&amp;` but just didn't format the XPath as code, so it just didn't show.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is fine as posted, but here are some common reasons that XPath's intending to match on element text might fail:

1. Additional markup such as `<b></b>` thwarts tests of `text()` node children.
   **Remedy:** Test the *string-value* of the element:

   ```
   //a[contains(.,'Cases &amp; protection')]
   ```
2. Whitespace causes comparison failure.
   **Remedy:** Use `normalize-space()`:

   ```
   //a[contains(normalize-space(),'Cases &amp; protection')]
   ```
3. False positive matches arise because other strings match on a substring-basis:
   **Remedy:** Test for equality rather than substring containment:

   ```
   //a[normalize-space()='Cases &amp; protection']
   ```

Webpage-related issues for unexpected failures for an XPath to match (apart from text content testing) include markup/content not having loaded yet, being dynamically generated, or residing in an `iframe`.